# Finding App Id under .ipa or .app

Tags: iphone, itunes

I'm building an application that search and recognizes any iPhone apps that user has in his/her computer. I would like to know a way to "extract" the id of the application from the .ipa file.

I was trying to do the recognition using only the App File Name, but I discovered that the File Name is not the name of the app in Apple Store.
Live Poker 6K Free by Zynga != Live Poker 3.7.ipa

The id i'm talking about is the app id, like in,
http://itunes.apple.com/app/live-poker-6k-free-by-zynga/id354901953?mt=8
the id is 354901953.

Does any body has a clue how can I manage to find this information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An IPA is just a ZIP archive. When you unzip it you'll find an `iTunesMetadata.plist` or `Info.plist` which should contain all info you need.

Comment: KennyTM, I already unzipped the .ipa but I couldn't find the iTunesMetadata.plist you told. Instead I found an Info.plist and this one doesn't have the numeric id I'm looking for.

Comment: Found the iTunesMetadata.plist. I was looking inside the Payload Folder, and it goes to the same folder that the .ipa is (Mobile Applications).

The field on the .plist is itemId.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's the exact path?

Answer (score 4):

If the app is not distributed via iTunes, i.e. it is an enterprise distribution or ad-hoc, you can find the bundle seed ID in the embedded.mobileprovision file. It's a binary, but you can read it in the terminal with

`cat embedded.mobileprovision`

You should see a line that says `<BUNDLE SEED ID>.com.yourcompanyname.*`

Answer (score 1):

That App ID is generated whenever you create the app in iTunes Connect (even before you upload the binary) and exists separately from your app bundle. I'm guessing the iTunesMetadata.plist file is only modified by iTunes Connect after you've submitted your binary

Answer (score -6):

It's impossible to extract app id from any *.ipa/*.app file.